# Stripe token error

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm trying to setup a section on my site that collects card details (using stripe), save as a customer, and charge at a later date. Looked through several tutorials and still getting an error, in particular:

Undefined variable: token in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/love-deals/admin/billing.php on line 21 failed to save customer id to db. I want to be able to save the customer id to a users table in my database (user already created) to be used at a later date for payments, but for the life of me I cant seem to get past this error! any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Kaylee

Here is my code so far:

payment page, with form:

```
<?php $userID = (int) $_GET['id'];
require('../inc/connect/config.php');
?>
<header>
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="admin.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
Stripe.setPublishableKey("' . STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY . '");
</script>';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/billing.js"></script>
</header>
<body>
<form action="billing.php?id=<?php echo $userID; ?>" method="POST" id="payment-form">
<span id="payment-errors" class=""></span>

<div class="form-row">
  <label>
    <span>Card Number</span>
    <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number" class="card-number">
  </label>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <label>
    <span>Expiration (MM/YY)</span>
    <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_month" class="card-expiry-month">
  </label>
  <span> / </span>
  <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp_year" class="card-expiry-year">
</div>

<div class="form-row">
  <label>
    <span>CVC</span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc" class="card-cvc">
  </label>
</div>

<input id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
</form>
</body>
```

billing.js:

```
function reportError(msg) {
// Show the error in the form:
$('#payment-errors').text(msg).addClass('alert alert-danger');
// re-enable the submit button:
$('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
return false;
}

// Assumes jQuery is loaded!
// Watch for the document to be ready:
$(document).ready(function() {

// Watch for a form submission:
$("#payment-form").submit(function(event) {

    // Flag variable:
    var error = false;

    // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
    $('#submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled");

    // Get the values:
    var ccNum = $('.card-number').val(), cvcNum = $('.card-cvc').val(), expMonth = $('.card-expiry-month').val(), expYear = $('.card-expiry-year').val();

    // Validate the number:
    if (!Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(ccNum)) {
        error = true;
        reportError('The credit card number appears to be invalid.');
    }

    // Validate the CVC:
    if (!Stripe.card.validateCVC(cvcNum)) {
        error = true;
        reportError('The CVC number appears to be invalid.');
    }

    // Validate the expiration:
    if (!Stripe.card.validateExpiry(expMonth, expYear)) {
        error = true;
        reportError('The expiration date appears to be invalid.');
    }

    // Validate other form elements, if needed!

    // Check for errors:
    if (!error) {

        // Get the Stripe token:
        Stripe.card.createToken({
            number: ccNum,
            cvc: cvcNum,
            exp_month: expMonth,
            exp_year: expYear
        }, stripeResponseHandler);

    }

    // Prevent the form from submitting:
    return false;

}); // Form submission

}); // Document ready.

// Function handles the Stripe response:
function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

// Check for an error:
if (response.error) {

    reportError(response.error.message);

} else { // No errors, submit the form:

  var f = $("#payment-form");

  // Token contains id, last4, and card type:
  var token = response['id'];

  // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  f.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "' />");

  // Submit the form:
  f.get(0).submit();

}

} // End of stripeResponseHandler() function.
```

and billing.php:

```
<?php
$userID = (int) $_GET['id'];
require('../inc/connect/config.php');
require_once('inc/stripe-php/init.php');

session_start();
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$errors = array();
if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
} else {
    $errors['token'] = 'Your payment details cannot be processed. You have not been charged. 
                        Please confirm that you have JavaScript enabled and try again.';
}
} // End of form submission conditional.

// Create a Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
"source" => $token,
"description" => "Example customer")
);
$custID = $customer->id;

try {
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users(cust) VALUES(:cust) WHERE id LIKE :id';
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':cust'=>$custID, ':id'=>$userID));
header('Location: ../admin/signup.php?joined');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'failed to save customer id to db';
}

?>
```

Comment: $token is undefined at the point you are using it. You probably want to move the bottom part of your code into one of the if/else sections.

Comment: Do a print_r($_POST) to make sure the Token is properly being passed to the backend.

Comment: your javascript uses jquery but you never include it

Comment: thanks for the replies. I've had a play about based on what everyone has said, still not achieving the desired result! i have included my jquery file now, an oversight on my part, also made a few changes to the php, now it is throwing the error i have set "failed to save customer id to db". I've tried print_r and var_dump and nothing is displayed... so i assume there is something wrong with my jquery...? if so im stumped, as jquery is not my strong point (at this point im questioning whether anything is!)... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated php:

```
<?php
$userID = (int) $_GET['id'];
require('../inc/connect/config.php');
require_once('inc/stripe-php/init.php');

session_start();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$errors = array();
if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    // Check for a duplicate submission, just in case:
    // Uses sessions, you could use a cookie instead.
    if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && ($_SESSION['token'] == $token)) {
      $errors['token'] = 'You have apparently resubmitted the form. Please do not do that.';
    } else { // New submission.
      $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    }
} else {
    $errors['token'] = 'Your payment details cannot be processed. You have not been charged. 
                        Please confirm that you have JavaScript enabled and try again.';
}
if(empty($errors)) {
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY);
// Create a Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Example customer")
);
$custID = $customer->id;
try {
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO users(cust) VALUES(:cust) WHERE id LIKE :id';
      $query = $db->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute(array(':cust'=>$custID, ':id'=>$userID));
      header('Location: ../admin/signup.php?joined');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo 'failed to save customer id to db';
}
}
} // End of form submission conditional.

?>
```